# Offline access using facebooker plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

If I use Offline Access on my rhtml page in rails application, how can I get the infinite session key from facebook? so that I can store it in the database & from onward users on my website do not need to connect to facebook again?

I'm using facebooker plugin in my rails application.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: [http://modelix.net/2009/09/facebook-connect-working-with-offline-users-data-access/](http://modelix.net/2009/09/facebook-connect-working-with-offline-users-data-access)

Comment: Is offline_access working properly?
Some of the users on my website are facing session timeout problem event though they have opted for offline_access.
Also this issue has been reported by number of developer at - http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6421